# How to SELECT NOT IN, but taking into account CASE SENSITIVE in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, i have a simple table Tb1

```
ID- Word
1 - Tom
2 - tom
3 - tom
4 - cat
5 - car
6 - CAR
7 - DEER
```

My goal is:

-1st, get unique CASE SENSITIVE Word, so this sql works fine:

```
select DISTINCT BINARY(word) from Tb1
```

-2nd, get unique Word (don't care about case sensitive), so use this simple sql

```
select distinct word from Tb1
```

The 1st query should show `Tom, tom, cat, car, CAR, DEER`(result1).

The 2nd query should show `Tom, cat, car, DEER`(result2).

so i want result1 minus result2: `tom, CAR`. SO i tried

```
select w1 from (select DISTINCT BINARY(word) w1 from Tb1) Tb 
where w1 NOT IN (select DISTINCT word from Tb1)
```

Since i got 200000 rows, so the computer got crashed & seem it return nothing. SO how to  solve my problem?

Comment: can u give 1 example?

Comment: I assume you are okay with the fact that the first version of each word will be left out and only the successive versions will show up. Also, is this your real use case: you allowed user registrations without converting usernames to lower case first and are now trying to figure out the duplicate registrants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join these two results using LEFT JOIN -

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
  ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Word VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES
(1, 'Tom'),
(2, 'tom'),
(3, 'tom'),
(4, 'cat'),
(5, 'car'),
(6, 'CAR'),
(7, 'DEER');

SELECT t1.word FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT BINARY(word) word from Tb1) t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(word) word FROM tb1) t2
    ON t1.word = t2.word
WHERE t2.word IS NULL
```

Comment: i ran 1.5 hrs already. Now the query is still running, so just let it run or sthing wrong with the query?

Comment: Try on small table firstly.

Comment: i think "not in" can do the job, but how to do "not in" with case sensitive?

Comment: Looks like there are performance problems, I don't think `NOT IN` will increase performance significantly. Have you tried on small table? I have added an example.

Comment: but it gonna take long if we have 200k rows

Answer (score -1):

**Referred Question No:**

> 16901755

*Alternative of NOT IN On MySQL*

Comment: Please tell mi whts wrong with this, im just telling duplicate question